# Way to count word occurence

Tags: pdf

Is there a way to count the occurrence of a certain word in document and PDF files? A solution which works on Windows will be most helpful.

I need to use it with various languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PDF:

In the terminal:

- `pdftotext YOUR_PDF.pdf YOUR_PDF.txt`
- `grep -ci 'word'  YOUR_PDF.txt`

Edit:

One-liner : `pdftotext YOUR_PDF.pdf - | grep -ci 'word'`

Comment: It can't be used for anything other English can it?

Comment: I can't see why not. Did you try?

Comment: No, then I will and get back at you. Furthermore, having to convert the PDF document into a text files makes me doubt about that the words will remain right... Well, won't know for sure until I try...

Comment: The `grep -c` option only counts lines, not words. (For example, try `echo hi hi | grep -c hi`; it only says "1".) As a work-around, split up the words on spaces: `echo hi hi | sed -e 's/ /\n/g' | grep -c hi`